How to close print message of libcurl (curl_easy_perform)？
I’m using libcurl intrface curl_easy_perform to POST data to server in interval.
libcurl version: 8.5.0
Following is my source code.
// Set the URL of your Flask server: *this->port_* is port number, *api* is the name of web interface (sendData)
std::string url = "http://localhost:" + std::to_string(this->port_) + "/api/" + api;
curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

// Set the POST data string
curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data.c_str());
curl easy setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

// set this option to disable echo message
curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curi_cb);    **// #1**
curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0L);               **// #2**

// write data callback, to nul
FILE *f = fopen("nul", "w");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, f);              **// #3**

// Perform the request
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl_);

// Check for errors
if(res!=CURLE_OK) {
    WLOG("curl_easy_perform() failed: ret=" << curl_easy strerror(res));


When I send a data to server, I get a print line like follows.
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2024 10:39:20] "POST /api/sendData HTTP/1.1" 200
In the code, I have tried following steps.

set CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to a callback (see mark #1). This truly close the response message, but not the printed line.

static size t curl cb(void* buffer, size t size,size t nmemb, void* lpVoid) {
    (void)buffer;
    (void)lpVoid;
    return size * nmemb;
}



set **CURLOPT_VERBOSE **to 0 (see mark #2), does not work.

set **CURLOPT_WRITEDATA **to null, does not work.


I want to send POST data in interval, I get a line for every PSOT, that will make my console fully with this message.
So, how can I close or disable this print line?

Why guessing and trials with CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION? Why not carefully read the manual CURLOPT_VERBOSE?

At 1st， I get the response message print to my terminal. So CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION is used.
CURLOPT_VERBOSE is set to 0, but not work. What's more, set CURLOPT_STDERR to null is not work.

Continue reading the linked manual, one step to success left.
